# Area Under a Curve - Right points

Tags: area, curves

I'm really conflicted about whether I did this correctly. Feedback would be appreciated!

[image]

2nd Attempt:

I'm still really confused because I've tried so many variations of this problem and still haven't gotten the correct methodology (the correct answer is 0.5313 which I got through a calculator) but I can't seem to get it?

[image]

Comment: ...using four rectangles...

Comment: Is that not 4 rectangles?

Comment: Your figure showing 5 rectangles....

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is incorrect. You wrote

$$Area=0\cdot f(0.25) + 0.25 \cdot f(0.25) + 0.5 \cdot f(0.25) + 0.75 \cdot f(0.25)$$

which is equal to
$$x_0 \cdot f(\Delta x)+x_1 \cdot f(\Delta x)+x_2 \cdot f(\Delta x)+x_3 \cdot f(\Delta x)$$

which means you

1. Took **left** endpoints instead of right ones (i.e., $0,0.25, 0.5$ and $0.75$ instead of $0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1$
2. Calculated the expression $f(\Delta x)\cdot x_i$ instead of $f(x_i)\cdot \Delta x$.

---

Your second attempt is better, but still incorrect. Answer the following questions:

1. If you split the interval $[0, 1]$ into $4$ equal-length intervals, what are these intervals?
2. What are the edge points of these intervals?
3. From (2), what, therefore, are the values of $x_i$ in the expression $$\sum_{i=1}^4 f(x_i)\Delta x ?$$
4. How is $\Delta x$ defined? The difference between which two numbers is $\Delta x$?

I suggest you try and re-read either your lecture notes or textbook, and answer the four answers above. I can check your answers if you do, and if you do, I believe you will see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much! However, I'm still a little confused. Is it possible for you to write how you would solve the problem? :)

Comment: @Eight8 A better idea would be that you try again, now that you know what you did wrong. You can edit your question with your second attempt, and if you then drop a comment, I will be happy to re-check your solution. Also, for formatting of your question, I suggest you check out this link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I'm still struggling to get the answer, any recommendations? I posted my 2nd attempt.

Comment: @Eight8 I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Approximation of an integral/area using right endpoint rule method **requires that the rectangles touch the curve with their top-right corners**.

**Figure**:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Here I only see 3 rectangles and I need 4?

Comment: Ok, I used right endpoint rule method with 4 intervals, usually it will result with 4 rectangles, but we have a special case, i.e. $f(x)=1 - x^2$, so try by yourself my approach, but with 5 intervals!
In other words $P_1$ will have coordinates $(0.2, 0)$...

Comment: If I may ask, which website are you using? I would like to generate a graph like this. Thanks.

Comment: I did this graph in GeoGebra...